# ASP.NET MVC Runtime Javascript Syntax Error without error code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

There is a Javascript syntax error

Form element:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UNIT, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.UnitList, "Value", "Text"), 
    "-- Select a Unit --", 
    new {onchange = "showSelectedValue" })
```

Javascript:

```
function showSelectedValue() {
           alert('Selected: ' + @Model.UNIT); 
           // Syntax error underlines the closing parentethesis of the alert function 
        }
```

I want to check what `UNIT` is being selected with the function `showSelectedValue`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor executes server side and javascript executes client side so you can't really mix them together; your code would put the *initial* value of `@Model.UNIT` into the script as a string literal and look something like `alert('Selected: ' + Whatever UNIT is);`, which is a syntax error because `Whatever UNIT is` is not encased in quotes.

The easiest thing would be to pass the `select` as a parameter to the `onchange` function.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UNIT, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.UnitList, "Value", "Text"), 
    "-- Select a Unit --", 
    new {onchange = "showSelectedValue(this)" })
```

.

```
function showSelectedValue(ddList) {
       alert('Selected: ' + ddList.value); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UNIT
    , new SelectList(ViewBag.UnitList, "Value", "Text")
    , "-- Select a Unit --"
    , new { @id = "ddUnit" });
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddUnit").change(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

If you want to directly get the value, use this in your script:

```
var value = $("#ddUnit").val();
```

Comment: isn't `#UNIT` enough? Why assign a new ID to the dropdown list? Just curious

Comment: Assigned ID to the dropdown list so that any events associated with the dropdown list can be written in your script and also the value can be directly fetched if required in other script functions.

Secondly, in javascript the values cannot be directly read from the Model. If you only want to get the dropdown value in the selection changed event as you specified in your question, your script (in your question) can be modified to:

function showSelectedValue() {
           alert('Selected: ' + @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.UNIT))); 
        }

Comment: Thank you very much but the other guys responded sooner.